# Laravel 5.2: defined user and get information from other database table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Update I have solved the problem I just forgot the `get()` here

```
$userDiplomas = UserDiploma::query()->where( 'user_id', Auth::user()->id );
```

but still didn't understand why I was not able to use this

```
Auth::user()->diplomas as $diploma
```

Here is my case

each user may registered to a diploma or more, now in the user profile I want to display all the diplomas that users registered to.

I made a new table called `user_diplomas` and here is the table migration

```
$table->integer( 'user_id' )->unsigned();
$table->foreign( 'user_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'users' );
$table->integer( 'diploma_id' )->unsigned();
$table->foreign( 'diploma_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'diplomas' );
```

when user are login and clicks on register now, it inserts 2 values to the `user_diplomas` table (user_id, diploma_id) this is working fine.

> now comes the question

I need to get the user registered diplomas and display them in his profile, please take a look at the `User` Model and the `UserDiploma` Model.

User Model

```
public function diplomas() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\UserDiploma', 'diploma_id' );
}
```

UserDiploma Model

```
public function diplomaId() {
    return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Models\Diploma', 'diploma_id' );
}
```

now trying to fetch the diplomas I try this

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->diplomas as $diploma)
....
..........
@endforeach
```

But no results are coming out!

I also try to do something like this in the `HomeController`

```
public function index() {
        $userDiplomas = UserDiploma::query()->where( 'user_id', Auth::user()->id );
        return view( 'trainees.profiles', compact('userDiplomas') );
}
```

but it didn't work too.

any ideas please how to make it work.

Comment: I am fool I forgot the `get` 
$userDiplomas = UserDiploma::query()->where( 'user_id', Auth::user()->id )->get();

Answer (score 0):

Change method in 'User' model to

```
public function diplomas() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\UserDiploma', 'diploma_id','diploma_id' );
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but still not working, adding the local-key didn't help